# How to extract specific pixels and make them more large?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uiimage, pixel

## Introduction: explanation of the situation

I have a UIImage like this:

[image: Input]

---

The image represents a "circuit" (running track).

## Problem

I need to detect the "circuit" (black pixels) and enlarge it (increase track width). Something like this:

[image]

I'm open to every suggestion / algorithm / other useful to get the expected result.

Thank you :)

Comment: Look for the dilation operation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for the tip! Thanks to [theory](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm#basic) and [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcBzsP-fvPo) I understood how _dilation_ works. Hope this could be useful for others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as @CrisLuengo said, **Dilation** is the solution.

I worked on it and I got a good initial result.

An example:

[image]

I need to improve the algorithm to enlarge the size of the shape more and more.

In my case I convert the image from RGB to Grayscale (pixel values range [0-1]. Then I process it in the following way:

1. Scan each pixel of the image
2. Check if the pixel is dark (pixel value < 0.45).
3. If true => I fill in black this pixel and all the pixels around it (considering the *structuring element*).

In the example the structuring element is the following:

0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0